# Google Apps Script: How to check contents of an array in a loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm having an issue where I want to check the contents of an array within a loop against an entered value on a spreadsheet, but I can't seem to get the results I'm expecting. I'm fairly new to JavaScript, so I'm sure I'm missing something or not understanding something obvious.
The code works with a sheet to create folders and templates within those folders (these are for marking projects). There are different departments that I would like the code to be able to differentiate between based on the 'variableNames'. In this case I'm trying to create a new sheet, and if the module is contained within 'audioModules' it will put 'Audio' into one of the cells of the newly created spreadsheet. The if statement at the end seems to be causing the issue. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
//adapted from https://www.bazroberts.com/2021/07/10/multiple-folder-maker/


//Get Folders sheet, get fixed name, get variable names
//Extract ID from folder URL, get root folder
//Make new folders in root folder with fixed and variable names

function makeL4Folders() {
  //Get data on Folders sheet
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const shFolders = ss.getSheetByName("Maker");
  const shURL = ss.getSheetByName("T_Links")
  const fixedName = shFolders.getRange(2, 2).getValues();

  let l4FirstRow = shFolders.getRange("C2").getValue();

  //Make variableNames array
 let variableNames = shFolders.getRange(2, 3)
    .getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS)
    .getValues();
    variableNames.splice(0,1);
  
  //Make audioModules array
  const audioModules = ["4FSC0AE001-Principles of Audio","4FSC0AE002-Desktop Music Production","4FSC0AE003-Recording Techniques","4FSC0AE004-Audio Industries"]
  //Get folder URL
  const rootFolderUrl = shFolders.getRange(2, 1).getValue();

  //Get Template URL
  const templateUrl = shURL.getRange(1, 2).getValue();
 
  //Extract template ID from URL
  var templateID = templateUrl.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
  var templateSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(templateID);

  //Check folder & template URL isn't blank
 if (rootFolderUrl !== "" && templateUrl !== "" && l4FirstRow !== "") {
    //Extract root folder ID and get folder
    const rootFolderId = rootFolderUrl.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
    const rootFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(rootFolderId);

    //Create a folder in the root for each of the variable names
    //and name each with the fixed and variable name 
      variableNames.forEach((variableName) => {
        var newFolder = rootFolder.createFolder(fixedName+ "_" + variableName);
        var makeSheet = DriveApp.getFileById(templateSheet.getId()).makeCopy(fixedName + "_" + variableName + "_Feedback",newFolder);
        var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(makeSheet);
           
           //I think this is where the issue is. I cant seem to get the comparison to work for modules that are in the subject of Audio 
          if(audioModules.includes(variableName) === true){
            newSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Front_Page").getRange(2,2).setValue("Audio");
            newSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Front_Page").getRange(3,2).setValue(variableName) 
          }
      })
      
}
}
```

[The spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51U3U.png)

I tried replacing the 'variableName' in the if statement at the end with a string and it seemed to work properly. I've also tried using the .indexOf method  e.g.`if(audioModules.indexOf(variableName) !== -1)` and it is not giving the expected output.

Comment: `variableNames` is a 2D array so `variableName` is still an array.  Do you mean `variableName[0]`?

Comment: use the Logger to see the actual value of "variable", maybe it can help. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger

Comment: Please provide a smaller more focused [mcve]

Comment: Thanks @TheWizEd, that seems to have fixed the problem. Much appreciated!

Comment: Apologies @Cooper, I'll know for next time!